# No such file or directory: 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6 during setuptools bdist_wheel

Tags: cmake

I'm building extension with CMake

```
setup(
...
cmdclass={'build_ext':Cmakebuildclass}
)
```

where `Cmakebuildclass` is a custom class.
Inside run() function of this class, I'm building the extension
It creates a temporary build directory where all artifacts get stored.
However, at the end I try to access it but it fails

```
error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temporary build directory [e.g. `build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6`] gets deleted once the targets are built.

It's copied over to the lib folder within build generally `build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/`
So use build_lib variable instead of build_temp

For code: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e5fe509054183bed9aef42c92da8407d339e8af8/Lib/distutils/command/build_ext.py#L108

Details:
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e5fe509054183bed9aef42c92da8407d339e8af8/Lib/distutils/command/build_ext.py#L57-L60

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this problem by force-installing torch, i.e. adding "--force" after "pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio"
remember to check the cuda version